# git thinks two files are totally different when not

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repo, for which I downloaded the files manually, and then did a `git init && git remote add origin xxxxxx`. Then I `git add`-ed all the files in the repository and made a commit and a `git pull`. Since I already edited one of the files slightly, I got a merge conflict. Now I have several copies of this file, a `LOCAL`, a `REMOTE`, a `BASE` and a `BACKUP` along with the original I had in the folder. If I do a `git merge` `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` are opened to be merged in an empty file. What I don't understand is, why doesn't git recognize, that the two files are almost identical? If I `diff` the `LOCAL` and `REMOTE` I can see there's no actual conflict. I can accept it might not be trivial which should overwrite which, but 90% of the content is trivial as they are the same.

Comment: The `.LOCAL`, `.REMOTE`, `.BASE`, and `.BACKUP` files are typically made by the `git mergetool` script, not by `git merge` itself. One runs `git mergetool` after `git merge` has exited with a failure to merge some file(s). It makes these four auxiliary files for its own purposes (.BACKUP) and to provide you a way to view the three input files that `git merge` failed to merge (`.BASE`, `.LOCAL`, and `.REMOTE`). It's then the responsibility of the merge tool you select to make good use of those three inputs. (I don't like any of the merge tools and don't use `git mergetool` at all.)

Comment: (Note, by the way, that this isn't intended as an answer - which is why it's comments.) Comparing the LOCAL and REMOTE versions isn't very useful to seeing why Git thought there was a conflict: Git compares, instead, the BASE to the LOCAL, and then (separately) the BASE to the REMOTE. It then tries to combine both sets of *changes*, applying both sets to BASE, to come up with a single final version. If you avoid the merge tool stuff and just open the work-tree file, you'll see the marked-up Git result. If you prefer the merge tools, you'll see the three input files plus whatever the tool does.

Comment: I checked, so BASE is empty, because there was no common ancestor to the two files in git's history, so it doesn't care they are the same files really.

Comment: Ah, yes - for an add/add conflict, Git just declares a conflict and takes its ball and goes home. :-)